# Pig Latin Console

Tags: c#, hadoop, apache-pig

Hi I'm doing Pig Latin for class, the instructions were first consonant is removed from the front of the word, and put on the back of the word. Then followed by the letters "ay." examples are, book becomes ookbay, and strength becomes engthstray. I'm having trouble because it doesn't do the first consonant.

```
// button, three, nix, eagle, and troubadour
Console.Write("Enter word you want in Pig Latin: ");
string word1 = Console.ReadLine(); 
string pig = ""; 
string vowels = "aeiouAEIOU"; 
string space = " ";
string extra = ""; //extra letters
int pos = 0; //position

foreach (string word in word1.Split())
{
    if (pos != 0)
    {
        pig = pig + space;
    }
    else
    {
        pos = 1;
    }

    vowels = word.Substring(0,1);
    extra = word.Substring(1, word.Length - 1);
    pig = pig + extra + vowels + "ay";
}

Console.WriteLine(pig.ToString());
```

For example if I do strength it will come up as trengthsay and not like the example

Comment: You're defining `vowels` near the top, then overwriting it later.  As for your issue, I'd suggest searching for index of the first vowel, then using that as your second arg to the first `substring` call (which currently only grabs the first character)

Comment: Also have a look at the documentation for [Substring(int)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hxthx5h6(v=vs.110).aspx).  You don't need to specify you want to go from `pos` to `word.Length-1`, you can simply write `word.Substring(pos);`

Answer (score 3):

You've got a number of problems there.  First of all, your definition of the problem:

> the instructions were first consonant is removed from the front of the word

That is precisely what you have done.  `strength` *does* become `trengths` if you move the **first consonant**.  You need to change your definition to ***all leading consonants up to the first vowel***.  Also, what do you do in the case of `eagle`?  Does it become `eagleay`?  Your instructions don't specify how to deal with a leading vowel.

This is another problem

```
vowels = word.Substring(0,1);  // This will overwrite your vowel array with the first letter
```

Don't worry about writing real code just yet, write some pseudo-code to work out your logic first. @Chris's comment about looking for the first vowel is a good one.  Your pseudo code may look something like:

```
Check if word begins with consonant
{
    If so, look for index of first vowel
    Take substring of word up to first vowel.
    Append it to end
}
Otherwise
{
    Deal with leading vowel
}
```

Comment: For all coders, but especially beginners, it's very helpful to take a step back from the code and look at the overall goal.  So many times I've found myself stuck with a particular line of code, then realised I was attacking it the wrong way from the start.

Comment: After all these years it just comes intuitively to me ;) But you're right it is a good approach for newbies (to google the pseudo code snippets)

Comment: One more thing I'll add is that piglatin words that start with a vowel end with "yay" [according to wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pig_Latin#Rules)